# distribute ipa to phone not added to the provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

How can i distribute an ipa to phones that are not added to my provisioning profile? i'm interested in not using TestFlight for some other technical issues. Do i require an enterprise apple account?

I found an example online. Here are some captions:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad-Hoc profile signed apps can only be installed on device which UDID are registered in the profile.

You could use an Enterprise account to sign the app as an inHouse app, which will allow you to install on any device.
But the Enterprise account only allows you to distribute to employee of the company on which name the account is registered.

Comment: No need to mention the name.

Comment: what are the criteria that determine that a user is a company employee? base mail address? i.e. abcd@mycompany.com => mycompany ?

Comment: There is not criteria, it is in the contract for the Enterprise account.

Comment: @TekayaMarouene wat name?

Comment: @rckoenes if i generate an unsigned ipa using a standard (non-enterprise) account, could that be distributed to people that don't have their devices registered?

Comment: For the enterprise account nog UDID needs to reregistered, just sign the IPA with the InHouse profile and it can be installed on any device. Just be aware that the contract officially only allows distribution to company employees. If the break the contract Apple might cancel the enterprise account.

Comment: @rckoenes ah so this is usable only for enterprise account, not standard account.. right now i have a standard account. i'm guessing there's no solution for me, no?

Comment: No, other then the standaard AdHoc or iTunes TestFlight there is not other option then the AppStore to distribute your app.

Comment: @rckoenes found an app that uses an exploit to share .ipas http://venturebreak.com/2014/11/15/install-movie-box-ios-8-1-without-jailbreak/